# x86: using register as an intermediate, why?

Tags: x86

lets say, `%eax` has content `0x123` and `0x123` has content `0x987.` and address `0xabc` has content `0x100`.

then, with `movl (%eax), 0xabc`, 
won't  `0x987` be moved as the content of `0xabc`? why do we need another register to do this? i.e.

```
movl (%eax), %eax    
movl %eax, 0xabc
```

Similarly,  `movl 0xabc, (%eax)` won't it move `0x100` to the address of `%eax i.e. 0x123??`  do we need another register as well to perform this?

Comment: Because the x86 mov instructions don't take two memory operands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because x86 doesn't offer memory-to-memory simple `mov` instruction. The can see all the offered forms [here](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html) and scanning the list you'll see essentially load (move from memory), store (move to memory) and register-register forms, but none that both load and store from memory.

x86 does offer more complex instructions such as `movsd` that do load and store from memory: that one, for example, moves 4 bytes from `rsi` to `rdi`. These probably don't really help in your scenario though: they still need two registers for the addresses as there are no "immediate" forms for the address. They are largely useful only in their `rep movs` forms to do a variable-length memory copy.